# Mobile Application UI Development, what should I look for?

Tags: mobile, android, iphone

I have been tasked to find a mobile app UI developer. I am not sure what to look for. We have a team of mobile app developers we are working with who asked us to come up with the UI. Do I need someone who can develop mobile apps or someone who is a graphic designer? I have a really good web application front end developer who I would like to utilize, but we are not sure if that is enough.

Answer (score 3):

"Do I need someone who can develop mobile apps or someone who is a graphic designer?"

We can't answer that question for you. You likely need both, among other roles. What roles do you currently have filled?

"I have a really good web application front end developer who I would like to utilize, but we are not sure if that is enough."

So, they're good with HTML, CSS and JS? Well, that'd fill the UI Dev role provided your mobile applications are being written in HTML CSS and JS. If not, then you may need a UI developer familiar with the particular framework(s) you are using to develop the software.

Typically, these roles will need to be filled:

- writer
- graphic designer
- ui designer
- ia
- usability tester/researcher
- ui developer

Those can all be individuals, or many individuals for each role. Or it can be a couple of people wearing multiple hats. It all depends on your team makeup and the type of project you are working on.

Comment: Great answer. One thing I'd add: if you know HTML and CSS you should be able to learn the paradigms used in Xcode for UI development. Or you could just do design and let the developers handle implementation.